# Wordpress setup, and finding the Authentication Code

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am going over to a Wordpress and my WP plugin is asking me about "Authentication Code" And I have no idea where to find it.

Comment: Probably best to post on wordpress.stackexchange.com. This is off-topic here (not a programming question).

Answer (score 1):

Without the plugin name it is hard for me to determine what specific *authentication code* is needed, so I'll assume that you mean the OAuth Client ID. Please, forgive me if I am mistaken. You can generate a new OAuth Client ID following this steps:

1. Open [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and select your project.
2. Go to *Navigation menu ⮞ APIs & Services ⮞ Credentials*.
3. Select *+Create credentials ⮞ OAuth client ID* at the top.
4. You'll be prompted to select an application type. In case of a Wordpress plugin you need to choose *Web application* and give it a descriptive name.
5. Click on *+ADD URI* and include your webpage URL. This action will whitelist your webpage to authorize this OAuth client.
6. Tick *Create* to finish the process and annotate your client ID and secret.

With this procedure you would have created an OAuth client ID and its secret. Now we can take this client/secret pair and use it to [request an authorization code](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#2.-obtain-an-access-token-from-the-google-authorization-server.) over some [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#calendar) scopes.

After getting an authorization code, you can ask Google to [exchange it for a pair of refresh and access tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code) that you can use on every call to the Calendar API.

Following these steps you would have created every authentication code possible, you just need to determine which one is the required for that specific plugin. Please, don't hesitate to ask me any additional doubts.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/QDSmx6f) I have the 2 first but the last one is I can't find.

Comment: Hi there @Ratzuka! If you already have the two first values and only need the third one, you are very close to reaching your goal. Input the first two values and save them clicking on *Save changes*. After the data has been saved, click on *Authenticate with Google* and your Wordpress setup will send a request token to Google as a result. You’ll be prompted to login and consent that request token, and as a consequence Google will provide the authorization code to your server. You'll be operating [these](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver) first three steps.

Comment: I seem to ither open  a blank new tap or get a pop up with

Fejl 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient